# Flutter Nested JSON with a List String as a Value in the Key Pair

Tags: json, flutter, list, api, dart

I'm hoping someone can help me.  I've been stuck on this for a while now.  I am reading a JSON from an API but I have not been successful in converting it and sending it back to my typeahead/autocomplete class.  I have attempted several different ways of doing this including JSON Serializable until it wouldn't work and I figured out it won't do nested JSON.  The JSON I am reading is not like any of the examples that I have found.  I have watched multiple tutorials and read all over stackoverflow. The key value pair I need to read has a key as normal but the value is a list of strings.  All of the examples I have found have an object with a key:value pair in the list[].  Can someone please tell me how to read and decode this the easiest way?

Here is an example of the exact JSON:

```
callback(
   {
     "status": {
        "code": 0
     },
     "total": 6,
     "dictionary_terms": {
        "compound": [
           "aspirin",
           "Aspirine",
           "Aspirin sodium",
           "Aspirin anhydride",
           "Aspirin methyl ester",
           "Aspirin calcium"
        ]
     }
    }
)
```

Comment: Try putting the json into quicktype.io and let it generate the dart code you can then use.

Comment: Tried this [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) mentioned by @GrahamD, it's definitely useful, it generated the correct model instantly to parse your json, you can use it.

Comment: Why go to the hassle of quicktype when you can use: `final compounds = json.decode(j)['dictionary_terms']['compound'].cast<String>();`

Comment: Hi Richard, that seems to fix most of the problem. I get an Error: type 'List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'. It is producing the list though on a print statement.  I have been all over the place with difficult solutions.  Serializable, factory, something with mirror, etc.  I knew there had to be an easier way but I couldn't figure it out.  Any ideas how to cure the type mismatch?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the object that json.decode(callback) gives, you have a Map<String, dynamic>.  So to access compounds in there:

```
_dynamicMap = json.decode(callback);  

    List<String> dictionary_terms_compound = _dynamicMap['dictionary_terms']['compound'];
```

Depending on where you are in null safety, you probably need to either check to make sure each key isn't null.  ie, this would fail if dictionary_terms or compound don't exist...so you would need to check for it before you can get the value from it.

So assuming they exist, you might need to put:

```
List<String> dictionary_terms_compound = _dynamicMap['dictionary_terms']!['compound']!;
```

The dart definition of your dictionary_terms object is a

```
Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>>
```

Comment: That will give: 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>

Comment: Then just change the List<String> to List<dynamic> or you could try casting it List<String> dictionary_terms_compound = _dynamicMap['dictionary_terms']!['compound']! as List<String>;  Not sure that would work, but fun to try.  Either way you should have the List.

Comment: Hi jbryanh, Thanks for your help.  I did use quicktype as suggested by other above.  Pretty cool tool but I think I have alot more code now than is needed.  I added your suggestions to my code and it's trying to read the map but it's not working because it says there is a format exception: Unexpected character (at character2) {status:{code:0}, total:6, dictinary_terms: {compound: [Aspirina, Aspir...  I will add my code.  I don't know what is causing the error.

Comment: class SugCompoundApi {
  static Future<List<SugCompound>> getSuserSuggestions(String query) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://private API site/$query/json? 
         limit=6');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.body);
    print('here');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      print('are we here?');  //this is the last test print statement that I get.
      final dynamic _dictionaryMap = 
          (SugCompound.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body).toString()));
      print(_dictionaryMap);

Comment: List<dynamic> suggestion = _dictionaryMap['dictionaryTerms']!['compound']!;
      print('are we getting here?');
      return SugCompoundApi.getSuserSuggestions(suggestion as String);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load');
    }
  }
}

Comment: factory SugCompound.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SugCompound(
    status: Status.fromMap(json["status"]),
    total: json["total"],
    dictionaryTerms: DictionaryTerms.fromMap(json["dictionary_terms"]),
  );

Comment: Sorry this is pasting in like this.  It looks like code then when I submit the comment, it pushes it all together.

Comment: could you edit your question and put in the code there, as code, so it's a bit more readable?